# Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set VMSS re-imaging without service interruption

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Wondering about the best way (Powershell or ARM template way) to change VMSS image gradually without service interruption of the whole Scale-Set.

Comment: I also have the same problem. In Azure DevOps, the release pipeline re-images the virtual machines in the scale set  (VMSS) requiring a restart. During this time, the IIS websites are not available. Is there a way to avoid this? Is blue-green deployment possible with VMSS?